# JavaScript push to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

How do I push new values to the following array?

```
json = {"cool":"34.33","alsocool":"45454"}
```

I tried `json.push("coolness":"34.33");`, but it didn't work.

Comment: array and objects are different in JavaScript http://www.karmagination.com/blog/2009/07/29/javascript-kung-fu-object-array-and-literals/

Comment: And this is not JSON. JSON is a markup format that goes inside string data, that happens to look like (and is named after) this Javascript literal syntax.

Comment: Note for future people: **The question is wrong**. It is **not an array, nor JSON**. Please read the answers.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It's not an array.

```
var json = {"cool":"34.33","alsocool":"45454"};
json.coolness = 34.33;
```

or

```
var json = {"cool":"34.33","alsocool":"45454"};
json['coolness'] = 34.33;
```

you could do it as an array, but it would be a different syntax (and this is almost certainly not what you want)

```
var json = [{"cool":"34.33"},{"alsocool":"45454"}];
json.push({"coolness":"34.33"});
```

Note that this variable name is highly misleading, as *there is no JSON here*. I would name it something else.

Answer (score 37):

```
var array = new Array(); // or the shortcut: = []
array.push ( {"cool":"34.33","also cool":"45454"} );
array.push (  {"cool":"34.39","also cool":"45459"} );
```

Your variable is a javascript object `{}` not an array `[]`.

You could do:

```
var o = {}; // or the longer form: = new Object()
o.SomeNewProperty = "something";
o["SomeNewProperty"] = "something";
```

and

```
var o = { SomeNewProperty: "something" };
var o2 = { "SomeNewProperty": "something" };
```

Later, you add those objects to your array: `array.push (o, o2);`

Also `JSON` is simply a string representation of a javascript object, thus:

```
var json = '{"cool":"34.33","alsocool":"45454"}'; // is JSON
var o = JSON.parse(json); // is a javascript object
json = JSON.stringify(o); // is JSON again
```

Answer (score 8):

That is an object, not an array. So you would do:

```
var json = { cool: 34.33, alsocool: 45454 };
json.supercool = 3.14159;
console.dir(json);
```

Comment: I only have one issue with that, I have some values that are might come in with other charachters, mostly like this.. "BRK.A" so I wont be able to do a json.BRK.A= 32.33;

Comment: You didn't mention anything about "come in" or from where you might be getting the values. So, based on your tags, I assumed vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: In those scenarios, you could do something like...
`json['BRK.A'] = 3.14159;`

Answer (score 6):

```
object["property"] = value;
```

or

```
object.property = value;
```

Object and Array in JavaScript are different in terms of usage.  Its best if you understand them:

[Object vs Array: JavaScript](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/javascript-understanding-objects-vs-arrays-and-when-use-them)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function to append to an array:

```
// initialize array
var arr = [
    "Hi",
    "Hello",
    "Bonjour"
];

// append new value to the array
arr.push("Hola");
```

Now array is

```
var arr = [
    "Hi",
    "Hello",
    "Bonjour"
    "Hola"
];
```

---

```
// append multiple values to the array
arr.push("Salut", "Hey");
```

Now array is

```
var arr = [
    "Hi",
    "Hello",
    "Bonjour"
    "Hola"
    "Salut"
    "Hey"
];
```

---

```
// display all values
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Will print:

```
Hi
Hello
Bonjour
Hola 
Salut
Hey
```

**Update**

If you want to add the items of one array to another array, you can use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
var arr = [
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "cherry"
];

arr = arr.concat([
    "dragonfruit",
    "elderberry",
    "fig"
]);
```

---

```
console.log(arr);
```

Will print

```
["apple", "banana", "cherry", "dragonfruit", "elderberry", "fig"]
```