# How to push an array to an Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push an array to an object in JavaScript.

This is how my object looks like (before pushing):

```
  const data = {
  columns: [
    {
      label: "InvoiceID",
      field: "InvoiceID",
      sort: "asc",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      label: "Vendor Name",
      field: "Vendor Name",
      sort: "asc",
      width: 270
    },
    {
      label: "Invoice Date",
      field: "Invoice Date",
      sort: "asc",
      width: 200
    }
  ]
};
```

So I want to add (push) another array called **rows** so it will look like something below:

```
  const data = {
  columns: [
    {
      label: "InvoiceID",
      field: "InvoiceID",
      sort: "asc",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      label: "Vendor Name",
      field: "Vendor Name",
      sort: "asc",
      width: 270
    },
    {
      label: "Invoice Date",
      field: "Invoice Date",
      sort: "asc",
      width: 200
    }
  ],
  rows: [
    {
      name: "Tiger Nixon",
      position: "System Architect",
      office: "Edinburgh",
      age: "61",
      date: "2011/04/25",
      salary: "$320"
    },
    {
      name: "Garrett Winters",
      position: "Accountant",
      office: "Tokyo",
      age: "63",
      date: "2011/07/25",
      salary: "$170"
    }
  ]
};
```

This is what I have been trying and it is not working.

```
const rows = this.state.rows;
data.push(rows);
```

In case you wonder, I am getting this `rows` from my database using `axio` There is no error in the array as it looks exactly as shown above. Problem is I can't push the array to `data` object. How can I achieve this?

Don't make this an duplicate since I am getting the array from my NodeJS server endpoint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript push to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173441/javascript-push-to-array)

Comment: Objects do not have a `push` method. You just assign a new property to them `data.rows = rows`.

Comment: `data.rows = whatever;`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a [dynamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language) language. You can add fields to an object at runtime. Just add a field to the object:

```
data.rows = this.state.rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such `push` function in Object like Array.

But you can do that like below:

```js
const objectValue = {
  array1: [
    {
      id: 1,
      value: 'one',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: 'two',
    }
  ]
};

const newArray = [
    {
      id: 3,
      value: 'three',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      value: 'four',
    }
  ];
objectValue.array2 = newArray;
console.log(objectValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to call bellow code:

```
let data = {
  columns: [
    {
      label: "InvoiceID",
      field: "InvoiceID",
      sort: "asc",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      label: "Vendor Name",
      field: "Vendor Name",
      sort: "asc",
      width: 270
    },
    {
      label: "Invoice Date",
      field: "Invoice Date",
      sort: "asc",
      width: 200
    }
  ]
};

data["rows"] = [
    {
      name: "Tiger Nixon",
      position: "System Architect",
      office: "Edinburgh",
      age: "61",
      date: "2011/04/25",
      salary: "$320"
    },
    {
      name: "Garrett Winters",
      position: "Accountant",
      office: "Tokyo",
      age: "63",
      date: "2011/07/25",
      salary: "$170"
    }
  ];
```

And then your Object will look like you want like below:

```
data = {
  columns: [
    {
      label: "InvoiceID",
      field: "InvoiceID",
      sort: "asc",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      label: "Vendor Name",
      field: "Vendor Name",
      sort: "asc",
      width: 270
    },
    {
      label: "Invoice Date",
      field: "Invoice Date",
      sort: "asc",
      width: 200
    }
  ],
  rows: [
    {
      name: "Tiger Nixon",
      position: "System Architect",
      office: "Edinburgh",
      age: "61",
      date: "2011/04/25",
      salary: "$320"
    },
    {
      name: "Garrett Winters",
      position: "Accountant",
      office: "Tokyo",
      age: "63",
      date: "2011/07/25",
      salary: "$170"
    }
  ]
};
```

Description: Everytime you need to push(add) a key in your object, you should use this syntaxt instead of push. because the object it's not an array.

for Example:

```
let obj = { key1:'it is key one','key2':['key2 array','key2 array']}

obj["your_new_key"]=whatever;

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript objects do not have .push() method. only array has .push() method.
If you want to add another key-value pair inside an object during run-time, you could do something like:
objectName[key] = value;

**In this scenario you can do : data[rows] = this.state.rows**